# PHP: Delete all array elements before a specific one

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Hi I've got the following array:

```
$days = array(
            1=>"Sunday",
            2=>"Monday",
            3=>"Tuesday",
            4=>"Wednesday",
            5=>"Thursday",
            6=>"Friday",
            7=>"Saturday"
            );
```

Now I want to make a loop that automatically removes all objects before number 4.

I tried this:

```
$startIndex = 4;
for($i = 1; $days < $startIndex; $i++)
{
    unset($days[$i]);
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: have you looked at `array_splice`? ie: `array_splice( $days,0, 4 );`

Answer (score 7):

A shorter solution may be given using [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$days = array(
            1=>"Sunday",
            2=>"Monday",
            3=>"Tuesday",
            4=>"Wednesday",
            5=>"Thursday",
            6=>"Friday",
            7=>"Saturday"
            );


$startIndex = 4;
$days = array_slice($days, $startIndex-1, NULL, TRUE);

print_r($days);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [4] => Wednesday
    [5] => Thursday
    [6] => Friday
    [7] => Saturday
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change $days to $i as $i is your index value.

```
$days = array(
            1=>"Sunday",
            2=>"Monday",
            3=>"Tuesday",
            4=>"Wednesday",
            5=>"Thursday",
            6=>"Friday",
            7=>"Saturday"
            );


$startIndex = 4;
for($i = 1; $i < $startIndex; $i++)
{
    unset($days[$i]);
}

print_r($days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array

```
$days = array
(
     1=>"Sunday",
     2=>"Monday",
     3=>"Tuesday",
     4=>"Wednesday",
     5=>"Thursday",
     6=>"Friday",
     7=>"Saturday"
);
```

Loop to remove all element before a specified index.

```
# Number to stop the unset.
$split_number =4;
# Loop through array

for($a=0;$a<sizeof($days);$a++)
{
    if($a < $split_number)
        # Unset element if condition is true
        unset($days[$a]);
}

print_r($days);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [4] => Wednesday
    [5] => Thursday
    [6] => Friday
    [7] => Saturday
)
```

If you wish the indexes to start from 0 again, you can use the `array_values`